# Fit large emailaddresses

Tags: titles, layout, author, email

I have authors with long email addresses. See the code below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{ACL2023}    
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
\title{PAPER TITLE}

\author{Author 1 \\ Example university \\ author1@emailaddress.nl\And 
         Author 2 \\ Example university \\ author2@emailaddress.nl\And
         Author 3 \\ Example university \\ author3@emailaddress.nl
          \AND
         Author 4 \\ Example university \\ author4@longemailaddress.nl\And
         Author 5 \\ Example university  Line two \\ author5@longemailaddress.com \And
         Author 6 \\ Example university  \\ author6@longemailaddress.nl
         }
```

The options below show the two ways I could think of to represent them. However, I find none of them aesthetical.

[image: Option1]

[image: Option2]

How can I make these emailaddresses fit and be on the same lines?

Comment: I don't know `ACL2023` package. It is not part of TeX Live. So I cannot test your code, even if i would add `\begin{document}\maketitle\end{document}` to give it a chance to be complete. And I don't know the definition of `\And` and `\AND` you are using. Usually authors in `\author` are separated by `\and` not `\And` nor `\AND`. So maybe this is a problem of the unknown package `ACL2023`. Maybe you can remove it. Without it, but using `\and`, there is no such problem, as you've shown in your example.

Comment: @cabohah, I found this template on Overleaf: https://ru.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acl-2023-proceedings-template/qjdgcrdwcnwp

Comment: @AndreyL. Thanks for your effort and the information, but questioners should learn how to make a minimal working example and to add links to packages that are neither part of usual TeX distributions nor can be found at CTAN.

Comment: Why don't you put the email adresses inside a \url{ } statement from package hyperlink? It's made to take care of long ones.

Answer (score 1):

You may rearrange authors as follows:

```
\author{Author 1 \\ Example university \\ author1@emailaddress.nl\And 
         Author 2 \\ Example university \\ author2@emailaddress.nl\And
         Author 3 \\ Example university \\ author3@emailaddress.nl
          \AND
         Author 4 \\ Example university \\ author4@longemailaddress.nl\And
         Author 5 \\ Example university  Line two \\ author5@longemailaddress.com
         \AND
         Author 6 \\ Example university  \\ author6@longemailaddress.nl
         }
```

The title area should be increased in this case

```
\setlength\titlebox{8cm}
```

[image]